# How to check an array with a dynamic value using jQuery.inArray

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

why does this jQuery.InArray not work? I am hoping that a coupon is added, the value is checked against an array. If it's in the array, fire the console.log otherwise do nothing. When I load the page I can see the array, couponArray, then Undefined which I am going to assume is because the initial couponCheck is empty.

Regardless, the last console.log still fires. The array is built from a ACF field and I can see that this works. Obviously this code will do more than just fire off a log but let me get it right in the first place.

```
<?php
    $couponCheck = get_field('coupons');
    
    wc_enqueue_js( "
        $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(){
            var couponArray = [" . json_encode( $couponCheck ) . "];
            var couponCheck = $('.woocommerce-remove-coupon').attr('data-coupon');
            console.log(couponArray);
            console.log(couponCheck);
            if(jQuery.inArray(couponCheck, couponArray)) {
                //$('.gift-with-coupon').show();
                console.log('Well done');
            }
        });
    ");
?>
```

Comment: `[" . json_encode( $couponCheck ) . "]` doesn't this make an array in array? `[ ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ]`

Comment: Oh this is embarrassing! You are so right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

so I have to understand how the jQuery.InArray actually works! It will just a numerical value of the string if exists. My conditional was actually missing a vital bit, as in something to compare with. So if the value I have dynamically assigned exists its value will be greater than -1 so output the console.log, If not do nothing.

```
if(jQuery.inArray(couponCheck, couponArray) > -1) {
   console.log('Well done');
}
```

So now it works. As someone I once heard said, 'You should read more...'

Comment: No, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?